# How to get session id of salesforce site

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

Hi I am Using the below statement to get session id of salesforce custom site page.

```
    var __sfdcSessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
    or
    var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
```

But the above two lines are giving 'NULL_SESSION_ID' when i see in the browser console. Is there any possible way getting the session id when working on a salesforce Site.

Comment: have u logged in to salesforce? if it a guest user then I guess it will be null

Comment: Yes, it is a guest user. Is there a way we can get it for guest user?

Comment: No this is not possible check this post https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000204984&type=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it a guest user then I guess it will be null

Check this link https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000204984&type=1

> Before Winter 15, it was possible to get the session id for the guest
>   user by using these codes:
>
> ```
> HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
> req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
> ```
>
> Now, an error code saying "INVALID_SESSION_ID" is returned if you try
>   to get the session ID of the guest user.
>
> This change ensures that you can still create a guest user session,
>   but doesn't allow a guest session ID to be set or created for
>   organization security.
>
> There are no recommended workarounds. Affected customers will need to
>   adjust their integration to not rely on a guest user session ID.